# How to do classification font by category (serif, sans-serif, hand writing, display)

Tags: fonts, opentype

Currenly, I'm using opentype.js (https://opentype.js.org) to inpect the font file. Now I want to get category of the font, can I do that?

Example: I have font file of https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Arvo, how can I know if the font is serif or san-serif? or the font https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Molle, how can I know if this font is hand writing?

Answer (score 2):

Consult the `sFamilyClass` and/or `panose` fields in the [OS/2 table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/os2) (which has nothing to do with the OS/2 operating system. It's a general metadata table).

However, note that these fields are *not* required to be correct in any way, because (a) classifications are highly subjective but more importantly, (b) there is no way to verify that the value set is actually true, so these fields are entirely freeform.

While a good foundry will make sure they're set to sensible values, someone "just making a font" can opt not to bother setting any kind of class/category information and the font will simply not contain any information for you to determine what kind of font it really is without opening it up and making a judgement call yourself based on the glyph outlines.